# Spring cloud config server failed working today, java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: spring, spring-cloud

My Spring cloud project has been working all the time until today. The error happened in Spring cloud.

in POM:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>Brixton.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

In bootstrap:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: configserver
  profiles:
    active: native
```

In main app:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableConfigServer
public class ConfigServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

When I tried to run, i got this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.cloud.config.environment.Environment.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.PassthruEnvironmentRepository.findOne(PassthruEnvironmentRepository.java:64) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.NativeEnvironmentRepository.findOne(NativeEnvironmentRepository.java:105) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.EnvironmentController.labelled(EnvironmentController.java:111) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.EnvironmentController.defaultLabel(EnvironmentController.java:97) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
```

Why did this happen? Is spring cloud being updated now?

Comment: Don't use a build snapshot? Try M1 instead.

Comment: Angel.SR3 worked for me, thanks

Comment: Works for me with snapshots anyway. Probably you just had a bad jar or something.